# Shell-spawning shellcode that is smaller than 295 bytes

Tags: shellcode, metasploit

I want shell-spawning shellcodes that is smaller than 295 bytes. Metasploit usually produces shell-spawning shellcodes that are (far) more than 300 bytes.

Or is there anyway I can compress the shell-spawning shellcode?

Edit: I need these shellcodes for Windows XP/2003.

Comment: Q: Are you a good guy, or are you trying to write an exploit?

Comment: @paulsm4 wannabe-penetration tester :) So good guy. But that involves bits of writing an exploit..

Comment: The size of the shellcode depends pretty heavily on what you want it to do...

Comment: @DCoder I forgot to write "shell-spawning"...

Comment: This question was also asked [on security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19632)

Answer (score 1):

Try using aleph1's shellcode. It should be small enough.
http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=49&id=14#article

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Shell-Storm?

http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/shellcode-windows.php

There are a few shell-spawning shellcodes, and other payloads as well. For example:

http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-710.php

http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-705.php

Or you would try a download-and-exec shellcode and put the Metasploit payload in an EXE file.